# API response Include milliseconds when serializing DateTime even if component is zero

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, jil

DateTimeStamp : 2022-04-29 15:19:41.350 after serialization 2022-04-29T22:19:41.35Z instead of 2022-04-29T22:19:41.350Z

I have fixed this using below code :

```
public static void ServiceJsonSettings(HttpConfiguration config, IServiceMetadata serviceMetadata)
    {
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonNewtonsoftJilFallbackFormatter());
        IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'",
            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
        };
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);

    }
```

Now for large object serialization i am using Jil Serializer configured as below:

```
public static readonly Options JilOptions = new Options(excludeNulls: true, includeInherited: true,
            serializationNameFormat: SerializationNameFormat.CamelCase, dateFormat: DateTimeFormat.ISO8601);
```

Using both Serializer Newtonsoft and JIL the output I am getting expected result : 2022-04-29T22:19:41.350Z.

But after testing it i found JIL serializer Serializer is trimming the zeros in millisecond part if it ends with 00 for ex:  DateTimeStamp : 2022-04-29 15:19:41.300 serialized to **2022-04-29T22:19:41.3Z**. On the other hand newtonsoft serializer produce expected result **2022-04-29T22:19:41.300Z**.

Is there any way to provide dateFormat as "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'" in JilOptions ?

Comment: May I ask why you need exactly 3 decimal places in the serialized data?

Comment: @Fildor it is business requirement from the business. in database millisecond are stored upto 3 decimal places so API response should have same.

Comment: _"up to"_ ... ".3Z" _is_ "up to 3 places". It is identical (in value) to "300Z".

Comment: @Fildor then 30 millisecond and 300 ms both are .3Z ? as per the Microsoft documentation we have datetime.ToString("fff") includes any trailing zeros in the millisecond value.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values
The fff format pattern includes any trailing zeros in the millisecond value. The FFF format pattern suppresses them

Comment: _"then 30 millisecond and 300 ms both are .3Z ?"_  No. 3ms is ".003Z" as in "3/1000 of a second", 30ms is ".030" is ".03Z" as in "3/100 of a second" and 300ms is ".300" is ".3Z" as in "3/10 of a second". It is expressed in "fractions of a second" ( hence "f" for **f**raction ).

Comment: @Fildor thanks got it but there should be some way to represent with trailing zeros in the millisecond value similar to newtonsoft 'fff' pattern in JIL serializer also.

Comment: If you absolutely want to, probably. I just doubted you actually need it. Haven't worked with JIL, so I don't actually know how to, though.

Comment: Do I read that correctly that your solution works for one zero as in "350" but _not_ for 2 zeroes as in "300"?

Comment: @Fildor yes JIL serialization for .350 it gives '.350Z' but for .300 it gives '.3Z' while newtonsoft with above configuration leads to '300Z'.

Comment: Ok, I can now confirm the behavior and NewtonSoft.Json doesn't play into it. I created a plain Console App serialized two objects. One with .300 and one with 350 and they end up as 3Z and 350Z using the ISO8601 format setting which leads me to the conclusion that this _could actually be a bug_? (Haven't found a way to get to 300Z, yet though)

Comment: @Fildor i have also created a console app below are result with JsonConvert:
1.with settings :{"CreateDate":"2022-07-01T16:32:44.300Z","UpdatedDate":"2022-07-01T16:32:44.350Z"} // Pattern : "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'"


2. default settings :{"CreateDate":"2022-07-01T16:32:44.3","UpdatedDate":"2022-07-01T16:32:44.35"}